# How can I adjust the size of this parametric plot output?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics, dynamic

I have a problem with the dimensions of the output of a `ParametricPlot`. What I'm trying to do is solve a differential equation using `NDSolve` and then make the resulting plot interactive so you can follow the solution as it changes through time. This is the code I have:

---

```
s = NDSolve[{Derivative[2][x][t] == x[t]^2, x[0] == 1, 
Derivative[1][x][0] == 0}, x, 
   {t, 0, 2}]; 
DynamicModule[{tr = 1}, Column[{ti = 1, tf = 2, 
   Show[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{t, x[t]} /. s], {t, ti, tf}, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray]], 
     
Graphics[{Dynamic[First[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{t, x[t]} /. s], 
                 {t, ti + 0.0001, tr}, PlotRange -> All, 
      PlotStyle -> Thick]] /. 
             Line -> Arrow]}], AspectRatio -> Automatic], 
Slider[Dynamic[tr], {ti, tf}]}]]
```

---

With this code, I get the following output

[image: ePlot output]

This is the correct plot, however, I think the axes proportions are not the best. I would want to compact the vertical axis and stretch the horizontal one.

I was looking for solutions to this problem and I found that `AspectRatio -> Automatic` should have adjusted the size based on the values of the plot. I tried this in the code I posted above, but it didn't solve the issue.

Could anyone tell me how I could correct this problem?

Also, I'm pretty new to Mathematica, so if the code is messy I apologize. It's basically put together by trying to stitch together examples from the documentation, so any suggestions about how I could change my code to make it better are also very much appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Try the potion `AspectRatio->0.7` and play a bit with its value.

Comment: @Alexei_Boulbitch -- The OP also needs to move the `AspectRatio` specification to the first of the `ParametricPlot`s in the `Show`.  I don't know where I learned this, but I don't remember seeing it discussed in the documentation ;-)

Comment: @RobertLee -- Welcome to the forum!  I think you've done great for being "...pretty new to Mathematica..."  You've run into some tricky and not so well-document issues.  Answer and things to try below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Show[]` uses `AspectRatio` and `ImageSize` from the first listed `ParametricPlot`.

I also specified the `AspectRatio`.

```
s = NDSolve[{Derivative[2][x][t] == x[t]^2, x[0] == 1, 
    Derivative[1][x][0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 2}];
DynamicModule[{tr = 1},
 Column[
  {ti = 1,
   tf = 2,
   Show[
    ParametricPlot[
     Evaluate[{t, x[t]} /. s], {t, ti, tf},
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray],
     AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
     ImageSize -> 350],
    Graphics[{
      Dynamic[
       First[
         ParametricPlot[
          Evaluate[{t, x[t]} /. s], {t, ti + 0.0001, tr},
          PlotRange -> All,
          PlotStyle -> Thick]] /. Line -> Arrow]
      }
     ]
    ],
   Slider[Dynamic[tr], {ti, tf}]}]]
```

[image]

Using `Manipulate` might simplify what you want to do in the future, e.g.,

```
s = NDSolve[{
        Derivative[2][x][t] == x[t]^2, x[0] == 1, 
        Derivative[1][x][0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 2}];
ti = 1;
tf = 2;
    
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   ti,
   tf,
   Show[
     ParametricPlot[
      Evaluate[{t, x[t]} /. s], {t, ti, tf},
      PlotStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray],
      AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
      ImageSize -> 350],
     ParametricPlot[
      Evaluate[{t, x[t]} /. s], {t, ti + 0.0001, tr},
      PlotRange -> All,
      PlotStyle -> Thick]] /. Line -> Arrow
   }],
 {tr, 0, 2}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I now see that I should have declared `AspectRatio -> Automatic` earlier. Thank you again for your help.